# Remove last line from a string

Tags: c#, string, winforms

I have a string that could look like this:

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
```

and I want to remove the last line (line4). How would I do this?

I attempted something like this but it requies that I know how many characters the last line contains:

```
output = output.Remove(output.Length - 1, 1)
```

Comment: Post your best try and we will help you with your problems.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Another option:

```
str = str.Remove(str.LastIndexOf(Environment.NewLine));
```

When the last line is empty or contains only white space, and you need to continue removing lines until a non-white-space line has been removed, you just have to trim the end of the string first before calling `LastIndexOf`:

```
str = str.Remove(str.TrimEnd().LastIndexOf(Environment.NewLine));
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have your string defined as:

```
string str = @"line1
                line2
                line3
                line4";
```

Then you can do:

```
string newStr = str.Substring(0, str.LastIndexOf(Environment.NewLine));
```

If your string has starting/ending whitespace or Line break then you can do:

```
string newStr = str
                   .Substring(0, str.Trim().LastIndexOf(Environment.NewLine));
```

Comment: Minor note: if `str` contains white space at the beginning of the string, `LastIndexOf` after `Trim` will not return the correct index. `TrimEnd` is safer. To trim both ends, call `TrimStart` after `Substring`

Answer (score 4):

You can split it, take all but the last line and use `String.Join` to create the final string.

```
string[] lines = str.Split(new []{Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None);
str = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines.Take(lines.Length - 1));
```

Answer (score 4):

Locate the last line break, and get the part of the string before that:

```
theString = theString.Substring(0, theString.LastIndexOf(Environment.NewLine));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
string[] x = yourString.Split('\n');
string result = string.Join(x.Take(x.Length - 1), Enviroment.NewLine);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var newStr = str.Substring(0, str.LastIndexOf(Environment.NewLine));
```